# Invert P-Value to get Confidence Interval

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, mathematical-statistics, confidence-interval, p-value

This is a weird problem, but please bear with me. I could use some insight.

Imagine you have a black box that spits out p-values for $H_0: \theta = 0$. We'll call this black box $g(\cdot)$. Assume this black box is properly calibrated to make Type 1 errors only $\alpha$% of the time.

Examples: I put $\hat\theta = 0.2$ into my black box and I get $g(\hat\theta) = g(0.2) = 0.6$ and I fail to reject $H_0: \theta = 0$. Next I put $\hat\theta$ = 1.5 into my black box and get $g(1.5) = 0.01$ and I reject my null hypothesis.

Given that I have a method for generating *p-values* with a closed form expression, can I invert this procedure to generate *confidence intervals* with $1-\alpha$ level coverage?

It seems that I should, but I'm getting lost in the details. A confidence interval can be found by inverting a test statistic. I do have a test statistic, $\hat \theta$, but I do not have a sampling distribution for this test statistic.

Comment: What are $\hat\theta$ and $g(\hat\theta)$ if not test statistics?

Comment: You're right. I will change my question a bit.

Comment: Now that I've thought about it a bit,  I do have a test statistic. I do not have a sampling distribution for this test statistic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you actually need is a function $g$ such that $g(\theta_0, D)$ returns a p-value for the test $H_0: \theta = \theta_0$. Then the collection $\{\theta : g(\theta, D) > \alpha\}$ is a confidence set with coverage level $1-\alpha$. In this case $D$ denotes your data.

If all you can do is test for $\theta = 0$ then I don’t think this is possible unless you make some strong assumptions about your $g$.

Comment: Could you explain why $D$ is needed?  If $\hat \theta$ is a sufficient statistic, then by definition of sufficiency $D$ would be superfluous.

Comment: @whuber when you have a sufficient statistic then you can use that in place of $D$, but this works even if you don't have access to a useful sufficient statistic. If you have a sufficient statistic, you can write $g(\theta, \widehat \theta)$, but the point is moreso that you need to be plugging in *both* some function of the observed data *and* some values $\theta$ (as opposed to just setting $\theta = 0$ as OP wants). Note also that this confidence region is valid with coverage level $1 - \alpha$ even if you *don't* base it on a minimal sufficient statistic.

Comment: It is redundant to use $\theta$ as an input--that's already incorporated in how the black box works.

Comment: @whuber In the OP it was assumed that $g$ gives a $P$-value *for the test $H_0: \theta = 0$*. You need to be able to test $H_0: \theta = \theta_0$ for every value of $\theta_0$, i.e. you need to be able to compute something like $g(\theta_0, D)$ for many different values of $\theta_0$.

Comment: @whuber $\theta$ cannot be "incorporated into how the black box works" because you don't know the true value of $\theta$.

Comment: I'm not trying to set up an argument: I'm trying to motivate you to justify and explain your post.  Because it appears redundant in requiring access to $D$, it is unconvincing, and even accepting that $D$ might be required, it simply states an answer without demonstrating it is correct.

Comment: @whuber I'm completely perplexed; how could you compute anything non-trivial  if your black box did not take some feature of the data as input? My answer is just a restatement of the extremely well-known method for constructing confidence intervals from hypothesis tests, just stated in terms of $P$-values.

Comment: The problem is that under some circumstances, you *can* invert this procedure to construct a confidence interval.  You hint at this in the last line.  Thus, there must be limitations to the scope and applicability of your answer.

Comment: @whuber Sure, if you know a lot about $g$ (for example, that it is structured based on a pivotal quantity) then maybe you can get away with just the test of $H_0: \theta = 0$. If you know that much about $g$ then I would argue you aren't really talking about a black box. Even in the presence of such a structure, I suspect it would reduce to what I proposed anyway.